# How to convert char to float?

Tags: c++

I am trying to convert two char numbers into float, but I am not getting the correct result.

```
char firstnumber = '1';
char secondnumber = '2';
float sum  ;

sum =  ((firstnumber - '0') /(secondnumber - '0'));
cout << sum;
```

The output is always **0**, rather than **0.5**, please enlighten me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're doing integer division, which truncates the result.  You need to add a typecast to get at least one of the `/` operands to be a floating point number.

```
sum = (float)(firstnumber - '0') / (secondnumber - '0');
```

Comment: From the bottom of my heart I thank you, I spent more than half an hour on it.

Comment: There might be a more C++-ey way to do that cast; I'm no expert on that stuff.

Comment: The C++-ey cast would be something like `sum = static_cast<float>(firstnumber = '0')) / (secondnumber - '0');`

Answer (score 3):

When you divide two integers, you get integer division. You want:

```
sum =  (firstnumber - '0');
sum /= (secondnumber - '0');
```

(Or some other way of accomplishing the same thing.)